# Kubernetes-Mesos in HA Configuraiton

Tags: kubernetes, mesos, mesosphere

**Environment**

`Mesos: 0.26
Kubernetes: 1.3.0`

Anyone out there using Kubernetes-Mesos framework?

Kubernetes-Mesos Question: Does current Kubernetes-Mesos support Kubernetes in HA configuration ? Having multiple Kubernetes masters talking to leader.mesos ? I tried to use it but I've got the following error on my secondary kubernetes master (trying to start `km scheduler`)

`"mesos-master[25014]: I0405 09:54:07.523236 25020 master.cpp:2324] Framework a979cde6-aa86-4286-b07f-e83e9ae4076e-0005 (Kubernetes) at scheduler(1)@10.9.158.237:42819 failed over"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not supported; only one k8sm scheduler should talk to mesos master. One option is to use Marathon to manage k8sm-xxx daemons, it will re-start k8sm master for failover.